How to filter LINQ on multiple values from other tables
I have a simple LINQ statement, but I now need to include data from other entities.
I want to receive Meta entities where the ViewId equals an Id from View and where View.SiteId = site.Id.
What I got:
Metas = await siteExp.MetaEntriesAsync(m => m.SiteId == site.Id || m.ViewId == ?????)

In SQL I would do something like:
SELECT m.* FROM SiteMeta m, SiteView sv WHERE sv.SiteId = 4 AND sv.Id = m.ViewId

The two entities:
public class Meta : DbAssets, IMeta
{
    public int? SiteId { get; set; }
    public int? ViewId { get; set; }
    public int? CultureId { get; set; }
    public virtual Culture Culture { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool OverrideTitle { get; set; } = false;
    public bool ReplaceExisting { get; set; } = false;
}

public class View : DbRef, IView
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Meta> Metas { get; set; } = new HashSet<Meta>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<ViewInfo> Infos { get; set; } = new HashSet<ViewInfo>();
    public int? CultureId { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public bool ReplaceTitle { get; set; } = false;
    public virtual Culture? Culture { get; set; }
}

Thanks!

will you include your code for SiteMeta and View classes?

@JerdineSabio done!


You need a navigation property from your Meta class to View class.


public class Meta : DbAssets, IMeta
{
    public int? SiteId { get; set; }

    public int? ViewId { get; set; }
    public virtual View View { get; set; } // add this

    public int? CultureId { get; set; }
    public virtual Culture Culture { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool OverrideTitle { get; set; } = false;
    public bool ReplaceExisting { get; set; } = false;
}


Then in your query, you could access that navigation property m.View.SiteId for filtering.

Metas = await siteExp.MetaEntriesAsync(m => m.SiteId == site.Id || m.View?.SiteId == site.Id))

or

Metas = await siteExp.MetaEntriesAsync(m => m.SiteId == site.Id || (m.View != null && m.View.SiteId == site.Id))


Another solution is to access the View table from the context and look for any Metas that has the siteId.
var metas = dbContext.Views.Where(v => v.Metas.Any(m => m.SiteId == siteId)).SelectMany(v => v.Metas).ToList();


yes that's a solution. But I think I can do it without altering the models, just altering the linq. I miss the IN keyword from SQL

@SteinLundbeckTech added another answer, but you need to access View from dbcontext. var metas = dbContext.Views.Where(v => v.Metas.Any(m => m.SiteId == siteId)).Select(v => v.Metas).ToList();

Now I got this. I haven't tested it yet, but it looks like it should do the job. Metas = from meta in await siteExp.MetaEntriesAsync(m => m.Active) join vs in await siteExp.ViewsAsync(v => v.SiteId == site.Id) on meta.ViewId equals vs.Id select meta

the second solution looks great! I'll test it out soon. thanks!
